# Using expressions inside tags

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, django-template-filters

I'd like to capitalize a string variable and translate it at the same time, but i can't find how to do this in the api docs.

i.e. this is throwing an error:
`{% trans {{ someString | capfirst }} %}`

Comment: did you try to remove the spaces? `{% trans {{ someString|capfirst }} %}` And what error does it raise?

Comment: Yes, its a Django wart that whitespace round `|` in `{{var|filter}}` isn't allowed!

Comment: Remove the braces, you can apply filters to variables directly in tags - `{% trans someString|capfirst %}`

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks, this works. If you make an answer i can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

In Django if you start curly brackets `{{` or `{%`, then inside you cannot open another one. Just use it, as you would use it without extra brackets.

```
{% trans {{ someString | capfirst }} %}

# change to:

{% trans someString|capfirst %}
```

PS. As I think it's not necessary, it's a good practice not to put spaces right before and next to `|`.